# Doing Symbolic Computations With Tensors And Differential Operators

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors, maple, mathematica

**Motivation**

Consider the following expression

$${\varepsilon}= \frac{1}{2} \left( \nabla \otimes u + \nabla \otimes u^\text{T} \right) \tag{1}$$

where $u:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ is a vector field, $\otimes$ is the tensor product, $\nabla$ is the the gradient operator and $\text{T}$ denotes the transpose. This expression rises in the theory of deformation of a continuum where it is assumed that the deformations are small. In fact, $u$ corresponds to a displacement field and $\varepsilon$ corresponds to the strain field which is a measure of deformation.

I want to compute the components of the strain field in cylindrical or spherical coordinates or any other curve-linear coordinates. So I go ahead by the usual computation rules in a curvelinear coordinates with basis $g_i$ and dual basis $g^i$. For example we can get

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \otimes u &= (g^i \partial_i) \otimes (u_j g^j) \\
&= g^i \otimes \partial_i(u_j g^j) \\
&= g^i \otimes (\partial_i u_j g^j + u_j \partial_i g^j) \\
&= g^i \otimes (\partial_i u_j g^j -\Gamma_{ik}^{j} u_j g^k ) \\
&= g^i \otimes (\partial_i u_j g^j -\Gamma_{ij}^{k} u_k g^j ) \\
&= (\partial_i u_j  -\Gamma_{ij}^{k} u_k ) g^i \otimes  g^j
\end{align} \tag{2}$$

Similarly, for the transpose we can get

$$
\nabla \otimes u ^ \text{T} = (\partial_j u_i  -\Gamma_{ji}^{k} u_k ) g^i \otimes  g^j
\tag{3}$$

Finally, using the symmetry $\Gamma_{ij}^{k}=\Gamma_{ji}^{k}$ for Christoffel symbols we can get

$$\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_i u_j + \partial_j u_i -2 \Gamma_{ij}^{k} u_k ) g^i \otimes  g^j \tag{4}$$

But this was really an easy case which we could do by hand. For example, consider the more complicated expression

$$\begin{align}
t &= [\tau - (\nabla \cdot \mu)] \cdot n - \nabla \cdot (n \cdot \mu) \\
&+ [(\nabla \cdot n) (n \otimes n) + \nabla n^{\text{T}} \cdot (n \otimes n)]:\mu \\
&+ (n \otimes n \otimes n) \vdots \nabla \mu 
\end{align}
\tag{5}$$

where $t$ and $n$ are vectors, $\tau$ is a second order tensor and $\mu$ is a third order tensor. The symbol $:$ is the double contraction and $\vdots$ is the triple contraction. It is more desirable to do this complex case with a CAS (Computer Algebra System) to avoid mistakes.

---

**Questions**

$1-$ How can I do these **symbolic computations** like in Eq. $(2)$ with a CAS like Mathematica or Maple?

$2-$ Is there already a code or software to support these kind of symbolic computations? If **YES**, can you kindly address it and do the symbolic computations in $(2)$ with the code or the software as an example in your answer.

Comment: $\nabla \bigotimes u$ is a matrix (field) whose each row is $\nabla u_i$

Comment: why do you think that mathematica for example is not capable of performing a change of variable and a gradient ? and the gradient in cylindral and spherical coordinates are even built-in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grad.html as the tensor product, so type $\nabla_{spherical} \bigotimes u$ in mathematica

Comment: @user1952009: Maybe because I could not do these symbolic computations in Mathematica. In fact, I am looking for a general solution which can handle more complicated cases not only a specific solution for this simple example that I mentioned here. :)

Comment: mathematica can handle any kind of change of basis/variable. I don't see the point. even after a change of basis it is a flat manifold so no problem for mathematica. are you asking about computing covariant derivatives in complicated manifolds ?? (where $g^î$ and $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ depend on the point)

Comment: so u imposed a (implicitly?) levi cevita connection?

Comment: @user1952009: I added the more complicated case to the question. :) Yes, I mean where $g^i$ and $\Gamma_{ij}^{k}$ depend on the point. :)

Comment: @tired: Sorry, I didn't get you! :)

Comment: so (in mathematica) the simpler is to define first the functional $u \to \nabla \bigotimes u$, I can swear you it isn't complicated if it  in $\mathbb{R}^3$, in a manifold such as in a Mobius strip or an hypolic plane, I don't know. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct.html

Comment: to compute the covariant derivative just in terms of christoffel symbols u have to make some assumptions about how ur metric changes under paralell transport. if u do so u can choose an connection the so called levi cevita connection which allows u to write ur covariant derivative purely in terms of Christoffel symbols. but i guess this was already done implicitly on the way to define the derivatives and should be always fine in deformation theory, so never mind :)

Comment: @user1952009: I am not that much expert in differential geometry. Talking in $\mathbb{R}^3$, our manifold which is a surface is smooth and well behaved so don't worry about it. :) I am just looking for a computational tool which I can use to do my calculations like the ones mentioned in the question in $(2)$. :)

Answer (score 1):

While Mathematica is surely capable of handling abstract tensors/differential geometry computation, not so much capability is already built in but for special cases. Very recent versions have added tensor capabilities and the ability to define arbitrary coordinate systems, you may want to give it a try but I have no experience with it.

Another possibilities is to install some additional packages.

- Atlas
  http://www.digi-area.com/Mathematica/atlas/guide/Atlas.php
  does the job. It is ok but, in my opinion, not great and it is not free. On the good side, it is not too complicated to use.
- This one
  http://xact.es/xCoba/
  looks great and is free, but seems pretty complicated to use and I have never got around using it.

Doubtless there are many other packages around. So bottom line is: for specific/sporadic applications you can probably get around with Mathematica built ins and a bit of programming. For more extensive use you are probably better of with a specific package (in Mathematica or any other CAS you like).

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the guide, Have you the experience with any softwares that you can provide some example with in here? :)

Comment: I generally use Mathematica + Atlas. Not ideal but it does the job! If you check the linked page there are very many examples of Atlas in use (look at the general tutorials part of the documentation) from which you can get an idea of what it does, so not much point in reproducing the code here.

Comment: Here  Mathematica built in capability from version 9 onwards is documented
https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/built-in-symbolic-tensors/
As I said I have no experience with it

Comment: Can you kindly do the computations in $(2)$ with ATLAS 2 and post it here? :) So I can check mark your answer. :)